# Solving the error "return makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, return

I would like some help, if you could, for unlocking me in my program. I would like to print the board and to be able to modify it later during the game.

But the compiler tells me "return makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]". I have searched for some solutions on the web but did not find something that could help me.

How can I solve this?

My header **`jeu.h`**:

```
    #ifndef __JEU__
    #define __JEU__
    void AfficherPlateau(signed char *plateau);
    int LanceDeDe(void);
    int setup(void);
    void jeu(void);
    signed char *plateauVide(void);
    #define SIZE 17
    #endif
```

My board management functions **`jeu.c`**:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "jeu.h"
    #define SIZE 17

    static signed char plateau[SIZE][SIZE] =
    {
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'},
            {'0','x','x','x','x','x','x','O','O','O','x','x','x','x','x','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','1','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','2','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','3','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','4','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x','x','x','x','x','x','O','5','O','x','x','x','x','x','x','0'},
            {'0','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','6','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','0'},
            {'0','O','1','2','3','4','5','6','W','6','5','4','3','2','1','O','0'},
            {'0','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','6','O','O','O','O','O','O','O','0'},
            {'0','x','x','x','x','x','x','O','5','O','x','x','x','x','x','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','4','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','3','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','2','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','O','1','O','x',' ',' ',' ',' ','x','0'},
            {'0','x','x','x','x','x','x','O','O','O','x','x','x','x','x','x','0'},
            {'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'}
    };
    signed char *plateauVide(void)
    {
        return *plateau;
    }

     void AfficherPlateau(signed char *plateau)
     {
        int a;
        int b;
        for (a = 1; a < SIZE-1; a++)
            {
                for (b = 1; b < SIZE-1; b++)
                {
                    printf("%c", plateau[a][b]);
                    printf(" ");    
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
     }

     int LanceDeDe(void)
     {
        int i = 1;
        int Lance = 0;
        srand(time(NULL));
        Lance = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        return (Lance);
     }

     int setup(void)
     {
        int nombreJoueur;
        int i;
        signed char PionsJoueurs[4]={'1','2','3','4'};
        int reponseIA;
        int nombreIA = 0;
        int erreur = 0;
        signed char *plateau = plateauVide();
        printf("Bonjour, combien de joueurs ?\n");
        scanf("%d", &nombreJoueur);
        while (nombreJoueur != 2 && nombreJoueur != 3 && nombreJoueur != 4)
        {
            erreur++;
            if (erreur >= 3)
            {
                printf("Seriez-vous en train de chercher la petite bete ?\n");
            } 
            printf("La valeure entree ne correspond pas a un nombre possible, vous ne pouvez jouer que de 2 a 4 joueurs.\nCombien de joueurs ?\n");
            scanf("%d", &nombreJoueur);

        }
        erreur = 0;
        printf("Souhaitez-vous remplacer un ou des joueurs par une IA ? Oui = 1\n");
        scanf("%d", &reponseIA);
        if (reponseIA == 1)
        {
            printf("Combien d'IA voulez-vous ?\n");
            scanf("%d", &nombreIA);
            while (nombreIA > nombreJoueur && nombreIA < 1)
            {
                erreur++;
                if (erreur >= 3)
                {
                    printf("Seriez-vous en train de chercher la petite bete ?\n");
                }
                printf("Vous ne pouvez pas avoir une autre valeur qu'un nombre entier allant de 1 à %d",nombreJoueur);
                printf("Combien d'IA voulez-vous ?\n");
                scanf("%d", &nombreIA);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Aucune IA en jeu.\n");
        }
        AfficherPlateau(plateau);
        for (i = 1; i <= (nombreJoueur-nombreIA); i++)
        {
            printf("Joueur %d, veuillez choisir vos pions avec 1 caractere :\n",i);
            scanf("%c",PionsJoueurs[i]);
        }


        erreur = 0;
        printf("%d\n",LanceDeDe());
     }

     void jeu(void)
     {
        setup();
     }
```

Finally, my **`main.c`**:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "jeu.h"

    int main(void)
    {
        jeu();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: "jeu.h" is missing...

Comment: @user3629249 Can you please stop filling up the comments with these suggestions? If you want to critique their code write an answer.

Comment: I vote for reopening, since the edit provided the missing info (it was hidden in the source code that failed to show the boundaries of each file).

Answer (score 0):

### In short

There are a lot of typing issue in your code, and depending on your compiler the message could be misleading.  The core issue here is the way you handle the 2D array (as well as a nasty error that causes memory corruption when you get to get it compiled).

### In very long, and step by step

Given the type of `plateau`:

```
static signed char plateau[SIZE][SIZE] = { ...};
```

The problems start when you write this:

```
signed char *plateauVide(void)
    {
        return *plateau;
    }
```

Unfortunately for you, this compiles fine.  But it's the same as `return plateau[0]`.  So the type is correct.  But you lose the second dimension of your 2D array.

This problem is proagated to lots of places. For example, in `AfficherPlateau(signed char *plateau)` you try to access it with 2 dimension, which should create a compilation error:

```
                printf("%c", plateau[a][b]);
```

**2D arrays are very tricky in C**.  Because:

- if you define them as you did, all the lines are put contiguously in memory, and if you want to keep the 2D, you need to pass it as a 2D argument.  This fixes the size of the array at compile time.
- If later you want to allocate such a fixed array dynamically, you could still use a similar construct.  However if you would like to use 2D arrays of dynamic size, say the used wants 20x20 instead of 17x17, you would have to work with pointers to pointers which have a different memory layout.

But in order not to make it too complex, just keep the 2 dimensions and the fixed width:

```
void AfficherPlateau(signed char plateau[][SIZE])
{
     ...// there you can use the 2D structure as you did 
}
```

You have to do this change for every function that used `*plateau`.  Unfortunately, you cannot define a variable this way, nor returning a value of this type.  I said, 2D is tricky.  So start with the following definition in your header:

```
typedef signed char (*PLATEAU)[SIZE];
```

Then you can rewrite your first function:

```
PLATEAU plateauVide(void)
{
    return plateau;
}
```

Then you can change the definition of plateau in `setup()`:

```
PLATEAU plateau = plateauVide();
```

Finally, you have a very nasty error here, in one of the loop.  THis could cause memory corruption and is difficult to spot with scanf arguments:

```
       scanf("%c",&PionsJoueurs[i]);   //<--- & is required for the address!!
                                       //(sinon ça plante ;-) )
```

And then, everything should compile fine.

[Online DEMO](https://ideone.com/6UsdGM)

***Edit:*** I almost forgot:  `setup()` has to return an integer.  It is a very bad habit of declaring a return type and not returning.

Comment: `If later you want to allocate such array dynamically, you would have to work with pointers to pointers which have a different memory layout.` - this is not true, you can use pointers to arrays as you show later on

Comment: @M.M sorry, I was thinking of an array of dynamic size.  Thanks for pointing it out. I'll edit.

Comment: You can use malloc to create an array of dynamic size in a single allocation , with a pointer-to-array. E.g. `char (*p)[m] = malloc( sizeof(char[n][m]) );`

Comment: @M.M. I've clarified;  This approach works as long as the width is fixed.  If the size should become dynamic, say a user input for a board of 20x20 or 150x150 instead of the fixed size, you'd need to use `signed char **` or use a 1D array with some calculations to transform 2D coordinates in 1D offset.  This is what I meant with tricky.

Comment: The code in my last comment doesn't require the width to be fixed. Although I agree that using a 1D array with offset calculation is simpler

Comment: @M.M indeed! My fault: I developed in C at a time this was not legal, and in the meantime I switched over to C++ and its vectors. But out of curiosity: how would you define a function with such a return type (like `plateauVide()` above) ?

Comment: Awkwardly... probably better to have it return `void *` and document the return value